# Extending the Cargo Space of a 2007 Honda Fit

Tags: honda

My wife and I are moving 1,000 miles away. Because we have dogs, we have to drive. We don't have enough stuff to merit a moving van, so we are loading up her 2007 Honda Fit with all of our worldly posessions. A little extra room would be really nice!

We contacted the Honda dealership, and they don't offer roof racks. The Fit doesn't have a trailer hitch and I think that is probably for the best, because its engine is only 80hp and probably can't pull a trailer. I have looked in to after-market cargo solutions but I am a fish-out-of water in this area.

Whats the best way to boost the cargo space of this car? Our cargo is going to be large plastic totes, suitcases and a couple road bikes.

Comment: Honestly, I would rent a van (if not a UHaul or equivalent).  The Lovely Wife and I did this shortly after wedding many years ago and it was much more convenient than attaching cargo carriers to her Honda.  She drove the Honda, I drove the van and didn't enjoy myself (but we arrived with all our gear).

Comment: It cost me 200 bucks to move 30 miles with a moving truck last time I moved.  I feel like renting a truck for 1,000 miles is probably going to be outrageous (especially including gas).

Comment: Yes, the cost of a van/truck is on the order of $700 (before gas) for that distance (based on my quickie Bloomington, IN => Providence, RI uhaul approximation).  You're kind of stuck with this vehicle, though: 80HP doesn't leave you with an excess of power.

Comment: [Mac beat me too it](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/3967/85), that's what I was going to post. You may want to consider shipping your items instead. The car top box will reduce you gas mileage, possibly by a lot, and if your not going to use it much may not be worth it. If the bicycle rack could be useful regularly it might be worth it

Comment: I have never used a service like this but it is a possible option[.http://www.doortodoor.com/landing-pages/door-to-door-vs-pods.aspx?cpao=111&cpca=Boston+Storage&cpag=G+Pods+Storage&kw=\[storage+pods\]&gclid=COawse3CobECFYio4AodEnq8iw]It would give you the option of packing and unpacking at your own pace. I believe most will allow for delayed delivery to allow you time to get set up before delivery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thule makes a rack that fits the Fit. You can then get a cargo box or some bike mounts (my personal choice would be the bike mounts, you may be likely to get more long-term use out of them), or both.

It'll be about $360 for the base rack, plus whatever bike mounts, cargo boxes, and accessories you get. I am a big fan of the Thule stuff.

[Thule vehicle fit guide](http://www.thule.com/fitguide/default.aspx?Language=en-US&Market=US)

looks like you need the [480 traverse feet](http://www.thule.com/en-US/US/Products/Base-Racks/Feet/480-Traverse-Foot-Pack), the [50 in load bars](http://www.thule.com/en-US/US/Products/Base-Racks/LoadBars/LB50-50-Load-Bar-Pack-2-Pack), and fit kit 1312.

You can always go with longer load bars to get some extra width. Two bikes and a box would definitely need more than 50 inches.

Comment: It turns out that a friend of ours gave us a nice bike rack for free, but this was a great suggestion.  I would have gone this route (with second-hand load bars and accessories) if it weren't for my wife's extremely generous linguistics professor.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a towbar installed, that'd be a useful option for when you have to move larger objects around.

Comment: I have reconsidered a hitch since I originally posted this question.  I was thinking it might be handy to get a hitch and a little hitch-mounted platform or bike-rack.